# Car Detection(Mask R CNN), How can I find the direction that car is moving?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I trained a model (Mask R-CNN) that uses instance segmentation and detects cars. Now I want to find the direction that the car is moving. The example from my model is here:
[image]

Any idea or logic about that would be super helpful. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/432

Answer (score 1):

A lot of work has been done on feature descriptors which would allow you to determine the direction of the cars. One such approach that I recently came across is [Oriented FAST and rotated BRIEF (ORB)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjegcShuIbyAhVjkWoFHQU9CykQFjAAegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fdata-breach%2Fintroduction-to-orb-oriented-fast-and-rotated-brief-4220e8ec40cf&usg=AOvVaw2GGfvuHrHU7XYU_xuFKLaG). The original paper was published in 2011. I read a recent paper and they had a similar approach to determine the direction of traffic. Here is the [paper](https://etrr.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s12544-019-0390-4).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches that you can try.

- If the images are continuous you can calculate the difference in the coordinates of a particular object and get the direction (coordinate system).
- You can add one more class for the arrows on the roads which usually shows the direction of movement of cars.
- You can train a model to predict the direction of the car with training data having images of cars facing in various directions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the exact method,
but I'm sure you can do this:
check 2 different frames of each picture for comparing the movement of vehicles([with open cv and arow drawing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-arrowedline-method/)).
and draw a Directional-Edge Due to the difference between the 2 desired photos.
I think it is a new idea.